# When "you" is the subject of a question

Tags: pronouns, responses

When we use "you" in questions, there are two possible pronouns we can use in answers: "I" or "we". It depends on the context

I just need to know if it’s true or false.

Comment: Are you asking whether "I" and "We" are the only possible answers to any question with the word "you"?

Comment: (1) Q. Do you have phones and running water in England? A. Yes, we do. (2) Q. Do you like ice cream? A. Yes, I do. (3) Q. Do you know the way to San José? A. No, sorry.

Comment: In other words - _you_ can be both singular and plural because the old second person singular _thou_ is no longer used in everyday language.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The word "I"  refers to the speaker.  The word "we" can refer to either the speaker and the listener, or the speaker and some third parties.  The word "you", refers to either the listener, or the listener and some third parties.

If a speaker asks a question, and refers to "you"  and means "the listener", then from the perspective of the listener the reference is to "I".  But if a speaker asks a question, and refers to "You"  and means "the listener and third parties" then from the perspective of the listener the reference is to "we".

This isn't really a grammar rule, it is just the meaning of the word "I" "we" and "you".

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you how you answer a question but of course if you use "you" in questions, only some answers make sense.

Some examples:

Do you love me? - Yes/No/Uh-uh/Uh-huh

Did you have good time? - Yes, we/I do

Why don't you join us? - What an awful idea! You're 2 times younger than me.

How many chairs do you need? - Five

Comment: Does anyone really say '2 times younger'?

Comment: I say and don't know any rule that forbids it

Comment: No rule, but 'half my age' is more common and uses fewer words.